# NHibernate - map a property of a runtime-defined type

Tags: c#, generics, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Alright, so I need to create a couple of tables, which need to be almost identical except for one field.

My model would roughly look like this:

```
class HouseGeometryModel
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   //More fields...

   public virtual HouseAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
}

class DungeonGeometryModel
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   //More fields, all identical to HouseGeometryModel...

   public virtual DungeonAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
}

class FortressGeometryModel
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   //More fields, all identical to HouseGeometryModel...

   public virtual FortressAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
}

//More models...
```

So, basically only the `Attributes` property differs between all the models here, so I thought there could be a way to unify everything into a single (generic?) class.

I could come up with two ways to implement this:

1. Make a generic class `GeometryModel<TAttributes>` which would look like:

   ```
   class GeometryModel<TAttributes>
   {
       public virtual int Id { get; set; }
       public virtual string Name { get; set; }
       //More fields...

       public virtual TAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   The problem with this is that I fail to specify a fluent mapping. The mapping should also become generic this way (to implement `ClassMap<GeometryModel<TAttributes>>`) and therefore it would be impossible to instantiate it with NHibernate.
2. Make the `Attributes` property `dynamic`. It doesn't work either because NHibernate treats `dynamic` properties as `object` when creating a `ClassMap<>`.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it generic way with a runtime `ClassMap<>` binding.

My model looks like this:

```
class GeometryModel<TAttributes>
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    //More fields...

    public virtual TAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

My mappings look like this:

```
class GeometryModelMap<TAttributes> : ClassMap<GeometryModel<TAttributes>>
{
    public GeometryModelMap()
    {
        Id(t => t.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(t => t.Name);
        //More mappings...
        References(t => t.Attributes);
    }
}
```

I wrote the following extension method:

```
private static FluentMappingsContainer AddGenericMappings(this FluentMappingsContainer container, Type genericType, IEnumerable<Type> genericArgs)
{
    foreach (var arg in genericArgs)
    {
        var newType = genericType.MakeGenericType(arg);
        container.Add(newType);
    }
    return container;
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory(string path)
{
    return Fluently.Configure()
                   .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile(path))
                   .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                   .AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                   .AddGenericMappings(typeof(GeometryModelMap<>), new[] { typeof(HouseAttributes), typeof(DungeonAttributes), typeof(FortressAttributes) }  )
            )
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => BuildSchema(config, path))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```